# How can I override the CSS of a site in Firefox with userContent.css?

Tags: firefox, css

In Mozilla Firefox, I want to create `userContent.css` which overrides the CSS of a site.

Where should I create the file (Windows 7)?

Comment: Related: *[How can I change link colors in Firefox and Chrome, but leave all other colors and fonts as they are?](https://superuser.com/questions/638250)* (also about file `userContent.css`)

Comment: You can use an extension called Stylus.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

1. Open Firefox and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to show the top menu, then click on `Help` → `Troubleshooting Information`
2. Click the `Open Folder` button beside the `Profile Folder` entry
3. Create a folder named `chrome` in the directory that opens
4. In the `chrome` folder, create a CSS file with [the name `userContent.css`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserContent.css)
5. Copy the following code to  `userContent.css`, replacing "example.com" with the website you want to modify and your own custom CSS. The `!important` is important.

   ```
   @-moz-document domain(example.com) {
       img { opacity: 0.05 !important; }
   }
   ```
6. Open another tab in Firefox, go to `about:config`, and set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` preference to `true`.
7. Restart Firefox.

Comment: A small update / modification for step 1; the Troubleshooting Information opens up a link `about:support` and in my Firefox (v20 nightly build on Ubuntu) it has an entry named "Profile directory" with a button "Open Directory" which opens up the profile directory `/home/tripleee/.mozilla/firefox/asdf1234.default/` in Nautilus.

Comment: You can remove `@-moz-document domain("...")` to apply the style to every pages.

Comment: Why is it supposed to be in the `chrome` folder?

Comment: @Septagram I think it's just always been that way… as I remember, `chrome` could also contain `userChrome.css`, which would style the browser interface ("chrome").

Comment: I know the OP asked about Windows 7, but for OS X users the path is ~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<profileid>.default/chrome/

Comment: And updating for 2015 and Firefox 37, the Troubleshooting Information page has an Application Basics section, with a Profile Folder > Show Folder button. That launches Windows Explorer, in which you select the chrome folder (or create one if it's not there already). Place the userContent.css file therein.

Comment: One small note, make sure that the folder you create is named, "chrome", with a lowercase 'c', otherwise it will not work on Linux.

Comment: It it is *necessary* to ***restart*** Firefox for it to take effect.

Comment: Also, comment characters in file `userContent.css` should only be the fully CSS portable ones: `/* */`. For example, `#` will not work and will break it in unpredictable ways.

Comment: Is a refresh required?  That would help for trouble shooting..

Comment: Starting with Firefox 69, you need to set the `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` preference to `true` due to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1541233

Comment: Don't forget to: set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true` (at this URL: `about:config`). Then **restart** Firefox.

Comment: Shortcut: If you open `about:profiles` you have the button to open your profile folder and a restart button to check if it works. Setting [legacyUserProfileCustomizations](https://superuser.com/questions/318912/how-can-i-override-the-css-of-a-site-in-firefox-with-usercontent-css#comment2289039_319322) beforehand is important, though.

Comment: @twigmac Having carefully made all the changes and restarted Firefox, I don't see any effect. I'm quite familiar with css too, and can confirm the elements exist on the page in question. Mozilla probably broke this for good recently.

Comment: @JohnO worked for me in firefox 72.0.2 as of today.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple custom css files so that I can keep the css for different sites separate?

Comment: @Moberg that is what `@-moz-document domain(example.com)` is for, it limits the enclosed CSS to only the domains listed between the brackets.

Comment: Also note: the "!important" is, in fact, important for this to work. :-)

Comment: as great as this is, it's annoying that I have to close and re-open the browser for styles to take effect.  anyone know of a workaround for that?

Comment: @billynoah I'm wondering that still Mozilla follows this setup.

Comment: @Rauf - I'm currently stuck on Firefox 78 and it definitely works.  Just that It seems the file contents are cached or something because changes aren't shown until I restart the browser.

Comment: From what I can see `!important` doesn't work or doesn't work the usual way. I tried to change `font-family`, and in the Developer Tools it showed that `font-family` was overridden, but in reality it used the original font. Resolved it by making the selector more specific.

Comment: @Ben If site has no property defined for some element at all, than !important is no so important to include in your rule.

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue Yes, you can press F12, and in stylesheet editor select you userContent.css and modify it, it will be applied in real time. You can also save it from there.

Comment: EDIT: You will have to reload browser first time you apply userContent.css to some site, @-moz-document does not seem to resolve if you just import it to stylesheet editor manually. But global styles still apply after manual import.

Answer (score 7):

There was an old extension called ChromEdit, which added a simple button to easily open user CSS for editing.

This was apparently compromised or withdrawn. Stylish was an alternative, but similarly this now appears to be defunct.

At the moment you just have to remember where the file is supposed to go.

Comment: I thought I'd got ChromEdit from the official list, but OK.

Comment: Based on recent reviews, Stylish should probably be avoided.

Comment: An extension is not the same as an actual user stylesheet. That's why Chrome is worthless garbage now.

Comment: @Synetech what are you talking about? This extension adds a button to open the stylesheet for editing.

Comment: Stylish didn't work for me. When I searched for help I found a forum topic in which a user said most users of Stylish have moved to Stylus because of better user support and more continual updates. Stylus is a fork of Stylish. Stylus worked for me without the need to restart Firefox. Usage of the plug-in is simple - navigate to the page you want to style, click the app icon at top-right of your browser, choose whether you want to apply styles to the current URL only or whole domain and write your styles. When you visit again, the icon shows number of styles being applied by the plugin.

Comment: @OrangeDog, I was under impression, that Stylish and Stylus works by inserting `<style>` into DOM, i. e. they modify *author* stylesheet rather than *user* one.  This is indeed a broken design, which makes it harder to use.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov I have no idea about Stylish. My original answer was about ChromEdit, but years ago someone changed it.

Comment: Stylish extension works for me as of April 2019. Fresh download and install..  It does not require a restart for new or edited stylesheets to be applied, though It might take a second or so to update open pages.

Comment: Stylish (2.8 stars in Oct 2022): https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/stylish/

Stylus (4.6 stars, recommended by Firefox): https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/stylish/

Both are still available. I'd go with Stylus.

I can also highly recommend Midnight Lizard for creating dark or tinted looks. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/midnight-lizard-quantum/