# How to restore Google "Cached" links?

Tags: html, css, google-search

On Google search, "Cached" links are available, which take you to a version of the page saved on Google servers. These links are quite useful if the source page is temporarily down or otherwise.

Back in July 2011 Google moved these links inside of an "Instant Preview" box. Many people from [**this thread**](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/kjja3dDrdio) and others either simply cannot find the new links or prefer the old location.

## Edit

To be clear, the question is **how to restore the links to the old location**. Answers for any browser are welcome.

Comment: Which browser?​

Comment: For Chrome/Chromium, I prefer the [Hide Instant Previews](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lhmknlddoobmlmhmgnpgniagcbnjjafp/) extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be fixed in Firefox by utilizing the [**userContent.css**](https://superuser.com/q/318912) file.

```
.vshid {
  display: block !important;
}
```

or inline

```
.vshid {
  display: inline !important;
}
.vshid:before {
  content: ' - ';
}
```

## [source](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/master/firefox/userContent.css)

Answer (score 2):

Not "block", but "inline" :)

This method can be used in Opera as well as Firefox, by entering the CSS code in a custom .css file and then using Site Preferences to set that .css file active for Google.

Here's a more complete version that also spaces the "cached" links off properly and puts them in the right colour.

```
.vshid {
    display: inline !important;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.vshid a {
    color: #1122cc !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution for other browsers:

I disable JavaScript on Google Search since I find it mind-numbingly annoying that the search field steals focus whenever I try to e.g. switch tabs with single-key shortcuts in Opera (which also will ruin the search results because of instant search). With JavaScript disabled, the "Cached" links are were they used to be, before the "Instant preview" change.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you want to obtain, howewer, to directly access the cached version of a page you can use "cache:" followed by the page URL as your search term.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can change a setting on the site with a cookie or configuring your Google account, then no, you cannot do that. Google moved the cached link into the Instant Previews and has no intention of changing it.

You will have to use a browser script/addon/extension/etc. to change it, which will depend on what browser you use. Your best bet for cross-browser compatibility is to use a [user-script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=cached). Most modern browsers support user-scripts, but the method to install them may/will vary.

There are several available that can move the cached link back, disable Instant Previews, add a link to the text-only version, and more.