# Change the firefox default style when a site has no css

Tags: firefox, css, styles

How can I customize my Firefox, so if a page has no style-definitions firefox will use a local stylesheet, that I can define myself?

I found this [addon: Context Style Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/context-style-switcher/), that can remove the stylesheet from a page, but that does look realy ugly.

It would be perfect, if I could define a per-site CSS, that is used every time I visit a page.

Comment: Try this tip from an earlier question [How to override the CSS of a site in Firefox with userContent.css?][1] 


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/318912/how-to-override-the-css-of-a-site-in-firefox-with-usercontent-css

Comment: that tip only changes the style on a certain site. I want to change the style on all sites, that have no CSS

Answer (score 3):

You can set the various options (color, fontsize, font family) inside `about:config` to a certain degree.  (type `about:config` as an address and open it)

some examples @ Firefox 62

```
browser.display.foreground_color: sets the text color
browser.display.background_color: sets the background color of a page
```

For further settings you can type in `color` or `font` or `size` inside the searchbar.

Comment: That works for the background color, but I couldn't find any useful setting. even `font.minimum-size.x-western` set to a bigger value than 14 is causing severe problems on nearly all websites

Comment: If it's just about the font size, try this option: font.size.systemFontScale Does that help? (change the value and reload a random site. I have it on 170)

Comment: that works. And you can edit the default font-family and link-colors in the settings menu under "Schrift" (german)

Comment: I found out, that setting a bigger `font.size.systemFontScale` than 100% makes big problems on many websites. I think the value is used as base for css `em` which is causing havoc if not starting on 100%

Answer (score 1):

## Use a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript)

...to automatically run user-defined JS. To make use of userscripts you have to install a browser extension called "userscript manager", which are available for all modern browsers.
[Learn more about userscripts](https://greasyfork.org).

Here is an sample JS that checks if `<head>` element contains any `<style>` or `<link rel="stylesheet">`. If no, then user-defined CSS is inserted:

```js
const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
if(head.querySelector('style, link[rel~=stylesheet]') === null) {
    head.insertAdjacentHTML(
        'beforeend',
        '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/spcss" />'
    );
}
```

Replace the `"https://unpkg.com/spcss"` with a URL of your CSS.
There are other approaches to [load CSS file using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript) or you can [insert a `<style>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript) to define styles directly.

I'm not sure if it's possible to load a local CSS file from `http://` page or access local filesystem from a userscript :(
but the script itself is a local file.

I've just published example above as a ready-to-use usercript: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/482860-default-css.

Comment: It's more robust to use `~=` instead of `=` in `link[rel~=stylesheet]` selector to match values like `rel="prefetch stylesheet"` and others. [See more](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#attribute-selectors) about attribute selectors