# How to convert HTML to PDF preserving visibility of content inside scrollable areas

Tags: firefox, microsoft-word, pdf, html

### Question

When I convert HTML content to PDF using

1. **"[Print Pages to PDF](https://addons.mozilla.org/EN-us/firefox/addon/print-pages-to-pdf/)" plugin for firefox** (scrollable area content are preserved however cannot see them)
2. **CutePDF Writer** Missing content (No Formating,But Readable)
3. Save as HTML -> Open with **Microsoft Word 2010** -> PDF (Formatting get destroyed)

Is there any way I can ensure that the content inside the scrollable areas are correctly visible ?

---

### Example Scenario :

[A Stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462110/encapsulation-design-smell-with-get-set-methods) screenshot

[image: A stackoverflow question]

**As you can see there are some code hidden by the scroll view.**

After conversion that non visible part is missing in the PDF

[image: After conversion]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Root cause

The root cause of the problem, in this specific case, is a deficient stylesheet for `stackoverflow.com`.

If you examine the [CSS for another site](http://cdn.sstatic.net/codereview/all.css?v=b6c8cf7181ec), such as `codereview.stackexchange.com`, you'll see

```
@media print {
    …

    pre {
        max-height: none;
        display: block;
        width: 600px;
        height: auto;
        overflow-x: auto;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;
        white-space: -pre-wrap;
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        clear: both
    }

    …
}
```

The crucial property is `white-space: pre-wrap`.

### Workarounds

You can use a number of Firefox plugins, such as [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/), or [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), to temporarily tweak the style rules before printing.  Such changes would not persist after the page unloads.

Alternatively, you can override the CSS semi-permanently, with no add-ons, by [editing `userContent.css`](https://superuser.com/q/318912/31983).  Specifically, the narrowest customization that would solve this layout problem is:

```
@-moz-document domain(stackoverflow.com) {
    @media print {
        pre {
            white-space: pre-wrap;
        }
    }
}
```

### After applying `userContent.css`

[image: Successful output]

Hidden code is preserved.

Comment: [Bug fix/enhancement request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269627/1157100)

Answer (score 4):

### Solution 1 : Output PDF (Readable,Styles are not preserved)

Use [Readability plugin](https://www.readability.com/apps) Or Website

> Readability is a free reading platform that aims to deliver a great
> reading experience wherever you are, and to provide a system to
> connect readers to the writers they enjoy.

With [Print Edit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-edit/) plugin

> Print Edit allows editing of the web page content while in Print
> Preview mode. Editing the web page prior to printing can compact the
> layout and remove unwanted content such as adverts, sidebars and blank
> pages.
>
> In Print Edit mode, any of the displayed content elements can be
> formatted, hidden or deleted, prior to printing in Print Preview mode.
> It is possible to switch repeatedly between Print Edit mode and Print
> Preview mode.

#### Steps:

1. Add Article To Readability
   [image: Add Article To Readability]
2. Change How It looks until satisfied
   [image: How It looks]
3. Click Print Edit
   [image: Print Edit]
4. Delete Stuff
   [image]
5. Press **Preview**
6. Press **Page Setup** and make changes
7. Press **Make PDF** then **Save PDF**
8. Rename the file to include PDF extension

### Solution 2 : Output MAFF (Everything is preserved,Different file format)

Use MAFF [(Mozilla Archive Format)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/mozilla-archive-format/)

> This extension enhances the way web pages are saved on your computer.
>
> It provides the following advantages over the built-in save system:
>
> - A complete page can be saved as a single file (web archive)
> - You can name files using the title of the page (title save)
> - The saved pages are faithful to the original (exact save)
>
> You can view and save MHT (MHTML) files, with excellent compatibility
> with Internet Explorer; but more importantly, you can use the MAFF
> file format, with the following advantages:
>
> - Save disk space, since MAFF files are compressed
> - Include video and audio embedded in the pages
> - Be universal, since MAFF is based on ZIP and compatible with Linux and other platforms
> - Use an open format, with no risk of vendor lock-in

---