# User Style Sheets in Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, css, accessibility, firefox-profile

I would like to adjust the styling of websites on a specific domain in Firefox, but the instructions I found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/318912/how-to-override-the-css-of-a-site-in-firefox-with-usercontent-css/1159278#1159278) are maybe out of date? At least they don't seem to be working for me. I have followed them as precisely as possible. There is no evidence of my CSS appearing in the debugger. I've also tried following instructions I found for IE without success. According to what I've found online, it seems chrome has disabled this capability.

Can anyone let me know if user style sheets are functional in Firefox or another browser, and if they are, point to some documentation on how I might use them?

P.S. I realize there are extensions that provide this functionality, but I can't use them due to security issues.

Comment: You can use Tampermonkey, it's well known and verified. Then use Userscript to inject the CSS.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I can't use an extension for this.