# How to hide website background images by default?

Tags: firefox

I universally consider background images on web pages as visual clutter. The images can impair text readability and website navigation, major examples include [Steam's community pages](https://steamcommunity.com/app/440/discussions/) and Wikia ([sample page](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Frank_Woods)). Because Firefox can detect background images (right click context menu > "view background image"), is it possible to hide (or preferably block the images from loading) on all pages?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, most background images on websites are defined in a CSS stylesheet by the rule `body {background:foo;}`

In Firefox, users can define custom CSS stylesheets that get applied to webpages that are loaded. When you specify a value in that custom stylesheet for a CSS-selector that is defined in the webpage that you load, those two values are treated as equally weighted and the question of which value gets applied in such case, depends on which value gets parsed last from the CSS. To give our custom value more weight over the value for `body {background:foo;}`, we add the tag `!important` to our rule. That way, it will be preferred by the browser to load, no matter which of the two values get parsed first or last.

To begin, let's create our custom CSS file:

- Open Firefox and press 'Alt' key to show the top menu, 
  then click on 'Help' --> 'Troubleshooting Information'
- Click the 'Show Folder' button beside the 'Profile Folder' entry
- Open the folder named `chrome` in folder that has opened in windows explorer
- If the folder does not exist, create a folder named `chrome` and open it
- Create CSS file with the name `userContent.css` . To create it, you can create a `.txt` file and rename it.
- Copy one of the following codes to `userContent.css`
- For painting the background of every webpage you visit in white color, paste following code

  ```
  body {
  background:white !important;
  }
  ```
- If you only target `callofduty.wikia.com`, which you linked, paste following code

  ```
  @-moz-document domain(callofduty.wikia.com) {
  body {
  background:white !important;
  }
  }
  ```
- To improve readability a little more on  `callofduty.wikia.com`, you could paste that code

  ```
  @-moz-document domain(callofduty.wikia.com) {
  body {
  background:white !important;
  color:black !important;
  }
  }
  ```
- When you are done editing the `.css` file, save it and restart Firefox.

For the other website that you linked, I could not figure out how to change the background there. So if you use the first code that I posted, be warned that it won't work with every website.

Using the technique described above, you can replace the color white with any other color and specify any existing CSS rule you can think of in our custom CSS file. If you later get rid of the changes you made, you can delete or rename the `.css` file we just created. On many webpages, following code will also work well to get rid of some background image without messing with the background color:

```
body {
background:none !important;
}
```

Concerning your question if the background image is hidden or blocked from loading, I'm not sure if it gets loaded without being displayed, using the method described above.

Sources:
[Rauf @superuser.com: How to override the CSS of a site in Firefox with userContent.css?](https://superuser.com/questions/318912/how-to-override-the-css-of-a-site-in-firefox-with-usercontent-css)

[Sarah Maddox: "How to override CSS stylesheets in Firefox"](https://ffeathers.wordpress.com/2013/03/10/how-to-override-css-stylesheets-in-firefox/)

[IT Support Guides: "How to use a custom style sheet (CSS) with Firefox"](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/computer-accessibility/how-to-use-a-custom-style-sheet-css-with-firefox/)

Comment: It is surprising that the method doesn't hide the background image on steamcommunity.com, instead minor page breakage occurs.

Comment: `background:none !important;` also turns the background to white, as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes, on that specific website (callofduty.wikia.com), the values 'white' and 'none' have more or less the same effect.