# How can I force Firefox to load stylesheets mis-reported as "text/html"?

Tags: firefox, html, website, css, mime-types

I'm visiting a website whose stylesheets have reported MIME type text/html rather than "text/css". Otherwise, they're just fine. I can't control the webserver or fix this problem - but I still want to be able to load the website. Unfortunately, Firefox refuses to load such stylesheets, telling me:

> The stylesheet https://some.where/whatever.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

How can I force Firefox (version 113 as of the time of writing) to load such stylesheets?

Comment: Does that site work on other browsers, e.g., Edge, Brave, etc.? If there is a fundamental error in the page, don't modify your browser to compensate.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Yes, it does work in Edge. I even know why the MIME type is mis-reported, I just can't do anything about it.

Comment: 1. Override the CSS: https://superuser.com/questions/318912/how-can-i-override-the-css-of-a-site-in-firefox-with-usercontent-css 2. Or perhaps save the website to HTML and modify the erroneous CSS?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: It's a different CSS for different pages; that's not relevant. Also, that CSS changes over time.

Comment: Firefox will accept  to load stylesheets with a wrong MIME type if a) they are served from the same origin as the document that requests them *and* b) the document is rendered in quirks mode.

Preemptive answer, I don't know if and how you can force quirks mode on a per site basis, or otherwise :(